# Productionizing Spark Pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

Using Sparkling Water/H2o v. 2.3 for prediction. I am trying to export a spark pipeline model containing H2o model.

Scoring will need to be done on a java based platform.

Please suggest best method for the same. I have been exploring on it but could not find anything substantial. PMML looks like an option only for pure Spark pipeline alone

The last alternative I have is to use Spark Streaming , avoiding it since I need to follow request response mechanism.

Regards,
Arun Lakhotia